# Delay between bytes using py-spidev for SPI communication on Raspberry Pi

Tags: hardware, spi

I am attempting to read/transfer data between an instrument and Raspberry pi 2, using the RPi as the Master and instrument as the slave. The data sheet states I must have a 9 ms delay between sending the command byte and the second byte, which I am currently unable to do using the py-spidev library for the RPi. The [docs](https://github.com/doceme/py-spidev) show a `delay` variable you can set, however when I set this, it seems to extend the amount of time the chip select is held low, but not much else. How can I actually introduce a delay between bytes without just bit-banging? Has anyone had success trying this?

Attached is an output from my Saleae logic analyzer showing the lack of delay with the following command:

```
spi.xfer2([0x03, 0x00], 500000, 0)
```

There is a 3 us delay between bytes and the /ss is held low for 84.2 us.

[image]

If I try adding the 9 ms delay, I see the following:

It has the same 3 us between bytes, but now the /ss is held low for the ~9ms.

[image]

Any thoughts/recommendations on things to try?

Comment: Worst case all you have to bit bang is chip select while sending two separate transfer commands.

Comment: Very true. I will have to try that asap

Answer (score 3):

The documentation is really vague about what a "block" is, but you might want to try sending your bytes using two separate calls:

```
spi.xfer2([0x03], 500000, 9000) # leave CS asserted after first byte, 9 ms delay
spi.xfer([0x00], 500000, 0)     # transfer second byte, negate CS
```

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion. It appears that the chip is still re-asserted after the 9 ms delay. Basically with the `xfer2` command it just adds a 9 ms delay before re-asserting the cs. I wonder how I can get it to stay low..?

Comment: An analysis of the [module source code](https://codeload.github.com/doceme/py-spidev/zip/master) shows that while the *intent* may have been as I described, the actual implementation of the two methods is functionally identical. I'd call this a bug, which means you'll either have to fix it or find a workaround for it.

Comment: @DaveTweed I did a quick experiment and xfer/xfer2 do behave identically.  All I did was send two xfer followed by two xfer2.  In each case the CS was de-asserted after each xfer/xfer2.

Comment: I will be making my best attempt to fix this in the py-spidev source and sending a merge request. I have also logged it as an issue.

Comment: Have you figured this out? I need to add a delay between bytes to accomplish a strange burst mode firmware upload in a device.